# Iptables-restore does not work with SNAT

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am using Raspbian on a Raspbery Pi (based on Debian 10) and I'm trying to use the following line in my iptables rule set:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 2.3.4.5/26 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

However when I try to load the rule file with iptables-restore I get the following error:

```
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--to-source"
Error occurred at line: 8
Try 'iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

I am 99.9 % sure that the line is correct, there are many tutorials online that use exactly this line. The option `--to-source` is even mentioned in the man page for iptables.

Any ideas? Is this a bug?

Comment: Could it be related to the `iptable_nat`and `nf_nat_ipv4` Kernel modules not being loaded [as described here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/iptables-change-in-current-whats-new-to-source-equivalent-4175677646/#post6138080)? As the poster states, “This can be caused that you upgraded kernel package but didn't upgraded kernel modules package.”

Comment: Thanks [for acknowledging my comment](https://superuser.com/a/1681417/167207), but in cases like this, comments are posted to ask if something works. And if something works, then you should encourage the commenter to post an answer [which is what I just did](https://superuser.com/a/1681567/167207). If my answer is helpful, please be sure to upvote it. And if it is the answer that solved the issue, please be sure to check it off as such.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be related to the `iptable_nat` and `nf_nat_ipv4` Kernel modules not being loaded [as described here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/iptables-change-in-current-whats-new-to-source-equivalent-4175677646/#post6138080)?

As the poster on that forum states:

> “Maybe you don’t load required kernel modules? It can be, I’m guessing, `iptable_nat` and `nf_nat_ipv4`. This can be caused that you upgraded kernel package but didn't upgraded kernel modules package.”

If that all seems weird to you, sometimes if you have run a package update in an OS like Raspbian, you need to reboot the system for the new kernel modules.

Comment: @A.B [My initial comment to their question](https://superuser.com/questions/1681400/iptables-restore-does-not-work-with-snat/1681567?noredirect=1#comment2581581_1681400) solved their issue as clearly indicated by their now deleted [comment as an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1681417/167207) that made reference to my comment. That is why I posted this answer and posted [another comment to the main question](https://superuser.com/questions/1681400/iptables-restore-does-not-work-with-snat/1681567?noredirect=1#comment2581829_1681400) that made reference to this all.